# Which of these statements about multivariable limits are true?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f :\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a map. Then
>
> **a)** $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \lim\limits_{y\to 0} f (x, y)$ exists implies $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to 0} f (x, y)$ exists.
>
> **b)** $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to 0} f (x, y)$ exists implies $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \lim\limits_{y\to 0} f (x, y)$ exists
>
> **c)** If both exist, then they must be equal.
>
> **d)** If neither partial derivative exists, directional derivative can still exist along some direction.

Could anyone tell me which are true statements above? Thank

Comment: It sounds like you have reason to suspect that only $b$ and $d$ are true (not so, as it turns out). If you put up your thought process, we could give you answers that were more to the point.

Comment: I knew one result which says: if double limit exists then repeated limit if both exists must be equal but the converse is not true.

Comment: sorry I predicted wrong. at this point I am sure 1,2,3, are false.